# searching with elasticsearch js with multiple fields

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Hi guys I have this code :

```
let test = await client.search({
      index: 'test',
      type: 'doc',
      body: {
        query: {
          match: {
            title: 'something',
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

this code is searching by 1 query which is title: 'something' , but I want to change it to search with multiple keys, for example:

```
 let test = await client.search({
          index: 'test',
          type: 'doc',
          body: {
            query: {
              match: {
                title: 'something',
                desc: 'some Qualifications'
              }
            }
          }
        });
```

but this code doesn't work and I can't find anything that will work like that, can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to combine all the `match` queries using a `bool/must` query, like this:

```
 let test = await client.search({
      index: 'test',
      type: 'doc',
      body: {
        query: {
          bool: {
            must: [
              {
                match: {
                  title: 'something',
                }
              },
              {
                match: {
                  desc: 'some Qualifications',
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    });
```